# Interface ambiguously inherited fields

Tags: java

I am going through JLS section 9.3.1 and i came across an interesting concept of ambigious inherited fields. This is the example from JLS

```
interface BaseColors {
int RED = 1, GREEN = 2, BLUE = 4;
}
interface RainbowColors extends BaseColors {
int YELLOW = 3, ORANGE = 5, INDIGO = 6, VIOLET = 7;
}
interface PrintColors extends BaseColors {
int YELLOW = 8, CYAN = 16, MAGENTA = 32;
}
interface LotsOfColors extends RainbowColors, PrintColors {
int FUCHSIA = 17, VERMILION = 43, CHARTREUSE = RED+90;
}
```

It is allowing to have ambiguous fields inherited. But when i try to reference the field and access it, it gives compile time error. Giving a compile time error for ambigious fields. My question is, at first point why the compiler didn't complain when the ambigious field was inherited. Why at access time, it's giving this issue? If we do the same when using classes., It allows. Why not in case of interfaces. My point is it shouldn't allow at the first instant only. Clarification on this concept will be pretty helpful.

Comment: I don't know the historical reason, but do note that in the example, not **all** the constants are ambiguous. So, what would happen if you do want to mix the interfaces and use it without the ambiguous constants?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interface fields are implicitely static final. And static fields are never inherited. You can *hide* a field by defining a new field with the same name, but you just need to qualify the field name with the appropriate interface to resolve the conflict:

```
PrintColors.YELLOW
```

or

```
RainbowCOlors.YELLOW
```

EDIT:

To clarify (hopefully):

The compiler allows you to use `LotsOfColors.MAGENTA` in the source code, although the field is actually defined in `PrintColors.MAGENTA`. But that's only to make your life a bit easier, especially when you reference a field from a superclass in a subclass.

In the byte-code, though, the compiler replaces the reference to `LotsOfColors.MAGENTA` by a reference to `PrintColors.MAGENTA`. It all happens at compilation time, and not at runtime like for polymorphic methods.

When you have an ambiguity (like for `LotsOfColors.YELLOW`), the compiler can't decide which of the fields you actually want to use. It can be `PrintColors.YELLOW` or `RainbowColors.YELLOW`. So, instead of taking an arbitrary decision, the compiler produces a compilation error, to force you to resolve the ambiguity. And you resolve the ambiguity in the source code by providing the actual class name, either `PrintColors.YELLOW` or `RainbowColors.YELLOW`.

Comment: No in the above example when i use LotsOfColors.YELLOW. It gives ambiguous error at compile time. That's what i am trying to figure out, if they are not inherited, why giving an issue and why even appearing in LotsOfColors as they are not inherited.

Comment: In my opinion it was a design-mistake that they even allowed `static` fields to be referenced unqualified in a subclass or implementing class.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: completely agree.

Comment: Great explanation JB :) thanks a ton. I completely understood the concept now. Somewhere i think so i should start seeing the byte code generated as well :)

Comment: @JBNizet even the specification there says `It is possible for an interface to inherit more than one field with the same name`, **inherit**... Suppose you have this code `interface A { Object temp = "A"; }` and `interface C extends A { default void m() {System.out.println(this.temp);}}` and on the other hand you replace `interface` with `class` and make `temp` static - the same bytecode will be generated in both cases.

Comment: @JBNizet it's like a static method - it is inherited but it is not overridable, same goes here - you will inherit the static field, but declaring one with the same name will only hide the one you inherited.

Answer (score 7):

Fields in interface are by default `public static final` so they won't get inherited

Comment: No in the above example when i use LotsOfColors.YELLOW. It gives ambiguous error at compile time. That's what i am trying to figure out, if they are not inherited, why giving an issue and why even appearing in LotsOfColors as they are not inherited.

Comment: While technically not inherited you CAN access them indirectly, its just not recommended.  The error is when two of the inherited interfaces both have the same field values, the compiler doesn't know which one takes precedence.